# Wordpress redirects from ip to domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, web

so i am running a wordpress installation on local network, which all computers can access using address or ip address. This doesnt work on mobile phones since everytime I try to connect using IP the address redirects to name. Any recommendations how to make it always use IP address?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more of a network question the programming question. But im gonna try to answer to the best of my ability anyway. The reason is that the server runs on your local network so when you try to connect to it from the same network as the server runs at you dont need DNS(Domain Name Service) you just need the IP but when you connect from a outside network it goes through a DNS service which translates the IP address to domain name and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I type IP directly to the browser from my home, the url changes to the address (server name). (for example lets say the the IP is 192.168.1.1:8081) and when i try to connect from my home computer using this IP the address changes to computer_name1:8081 but the site doesn't load. If I edit the hosts file should it work? Also how to make it work so that I can open the website using my phone?